# how to check userroles in each controller in nestjs

Tags: nestjs

There was no answer to the question I left before, so I'm writing again.

Please understand.

I am making a project using nestjs.

I want to prevent users with a specific role in all controllers except for one controller.

I know, add @UseGuard(RoleGuard) @Role(UserRole.Guest) to each controller.

But I have a lot of controllers, and more will be added over and over again.

Is there a way to do it all at once like middleware?

thank you!

Comment: just bind the guard globally and use `UserRole.Guest` as the default role.

Comment: @MicaelLevi Thanks for the comment. What I was wondering was how to use it globally!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NestJS authentication provides different mechanisms like:

1. [Extending guards](https://docs.nestjs.com/security/authentication#extending-guards)
2. [Enable authentication globally](https://docs.nestjs.com/security/authentication#enable-authentication-globally)

For your specific use case, with the first mechanism, you can extend your auth guard to check if the user has a specific role.

```
import {
  ExecutionContext,
  Injectable,
  UnauthorizedException,
} from '@nestjs/common';
import { AuthGuard } from '@nestjs/passport';

@Injectable()
export class JwtAuthGuard extends AuthGuard('jwt') {
  canActivate(context: ExecutionContext) {
    return super.canActivate(context);
  }

  handleRequest(err, user, info) {
    if (err || !user) { <------------ You can check not only the user's existence but also the role here.
      throw err || new UnauthorizedException();
    }
    return user;
  }
}
```

And with the second mechanism, you can define the auth guard globally in any one of your modules so that you don't have to add it over and over again in controllers.

```
providers: [
  {
    provide: APP_GUARD,
    useClass: JwtAuthGuard,
  },
],
```

Note that if you expect the different controllers to be accessed with different user roles then you have to define the specific roles guard in the controllers themselves.